# ReportViewer1 Does Not Exist in the Current Context

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2012

I am new to ASP.NET and am trying to create a report viewer object on my webpage. I am needing to pass default authentication to the server. The code I am using can be found here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.reporting.webforms.ireportservercredentials.aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=csharp#code-snippet-4

Here is the code for the report viewer:

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="True" CodeBehind="WebForm1.aspx.cs" Inherits="WebApplication3.WebForm1" %>

<%@ Register Assembly="Microsoft.ReportViewer.WebForms, Version=11.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89845dcd8080cc91" Namespace="Microsoft.Reporting.WebForms" TagPrefix="rsweb" %>

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>
        <asp:ScriptManager runat="server">   </asp:ScriptManager>
        <rsweb:ReportViewer ID="ReportViewer1" runat="server" Font-Names="Verdana" Font-Size="8pt" ProcessingMode="Remote" WaitMessageFont-Names="Verdana" WaitMessageFont-Size="14pt">
            <ServerReport ReportPath="hoopstatist/Reports/Shooting Analysis" ReportServerUrl="https://rs2k1201.discountasp.net/reports" />
        </rsweb:ReportViewer>

    </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Here is the code that has errors:

```
public partial class _Default : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void Page_Init(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //It has issues here for ReportViewer1
        ReportViewer1.ServerReport.ReportServerCredentials =
            new MyReportServerCredentials();


    }
}
```

Here is the error:

```
Error   1   The name 'ReportViewer1' does not exist in the current context  c:\users\nile\documents\visual studio 2012\Projects\WebApplication3\WebApplication3\WebForm1.aspx.cs    18  9   WebApplication3
```

Comment: did you try same code in page+load eent?

Comment: Is ReportViewer inside some other container control?

Comment: I have added all of the code for the web form.

Comment: Are u sure that CS file belongs to that ASPX file? Looks like ASPX is WebForm1.aspx an CS is from Default.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Check the .designer.cs file and ensure your namespace matches, or remove it if you don't have one. That can throw the intellisense and/or builder off sometimes.